# sql deleting CELL DATA/RECORD from table

Tags: sql

In my column called `City` there are 10+ rows having same city and each row displays the same city name. What I want is after `ORDER BY CITY`, I should get the city name for the 1st row having that city and then the next rows should display `CITY="-"` or `NULL` value to indicate that the details are of the same city.

Attempts: I tried a lot to solve this problem for weeks.

1. I used this, but the output gave me any order of `ZONES(citynames)`. To select those rows where repeated city names are displayed however, after this ordering them becomes impossible.

   ```
   WITH T1 AS
   (SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ZONE ORDER BY Date ASC) AS ROWID 
         FROM Try2)T
   WHERE T.ROWID > 1)
   UPDATE T1 SET ZONE='NULL'
   ```
2. Got an advice of using `PIVOT`. But after studying didn't get much, pivot examples given to swap rows with cols, not for such problems.
3. Numerous examples online to delete duplicate rows, but very few to replace the repeating value by other value (here `--`). Tried using temporary table too, but syntax errors killed me, still working on it.

Since I have 21 different cities, I need to find duplicates of all of them and replace city names in each one without altering other row details. Being a novice I have no idea how to implement this. Could anybody help me out or point me to a reference?

Comment: Simple answer: Don't do it via SQL. SQL is there to get you the data, nothing more. It's not there to format your data in any way. Do that in a layer above with PHP or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not want to change the original data.  At least in my opinion.  A table is inherently not ordered, so there is no concept of "first".

Instead, do it when you fetch the data.  Let me assume that there is a field called "date" that defines the first one.

```
select (case when try2.date = tc.mindate then try2.city else '-' end) as city,
       <rest of the columns>
from try2 join
     (select city, min(date) as mindate
      from try2
      group by city
     ) tc
     on try2.city = tc.city 
order by city, date
```

You can do something similar with ranking functions (row_number()).